# Displaying data from multiple lists on a single screen powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, display-form, powerapp

I am storing data in multiple related lists in SharePoint. Saving/displaying data on a single list is pretty straight forward.

Any suggestion on how I could possibly display data on a single screen in PowerApp?

I would really appreciate suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly have two galleries on the same screen, and set the source of one to be filtered based on the selected value of the other. [Here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Creating-Apps/Powerapps-related-list-items/td-p/143931) is an example. (while the example uses multiple screens, putting all controls on one screen wouldn't change any of the form logic.)